# How to apply a microservices architecture to a financial products consulting website? is it practical?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I'm working on a website which displays financial products, their related documents and performance charts...

It is actually a complex monolithic application which has a lot of code and functionality.

Is it practical to divide this application into a microservices architecture?

knowing that users do not login on the website, there is no business transactions, they simply search, consult and see products and related information on the website

Answer (score 0):

> knowing that users do not login on the website, there is no business
>   transactions

You don't have to consider these for transitioning to microservices architecture from monolith. If you are sure that your system can be split/sliced into multiple services, the database is splittable and you really need to go for microservices in terms of your business need, you can consider. Once you decide and start iterating, you will get more clear pictures how to split the features and independent vertical slices on your application.

For instance, if you have recommendation feature in your system, you can consider an independent recommendation service with separate storage system. If at any case, the recommendation service is down, with proper fallback mechanism, the whole system should  operate successfully without recommendation service (For example, it can show top X items to all users when recommendation service is not working).

The short answer is - your system can be considered as a candidate for microservices architecture. But before jumping into, [you should consider these things](http://blog.shippable.com/7-things-to-consider-while-moving-to-microservices).